Jmeter Test steps recorder is not saving the steps after stop the record in chrome
Jmeter Test steps recorder is not saving the steps after stop the record in chrome I checked the proxy import the certificates and trying ways but still the steps are not saving in jmeter
trying ways but still the steps are not saving in jmeter

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Check jmeter.log file for any suspicious entries, normally if something is wrong you can find a reason or at least a clue there.
Check Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder documentation chapter for step-by-step guide. If you need further assistance you will need to show us your browser configuration, JMeter configuration, jmeter.log file and browser console output
Also there is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: JMeter Chrome Extension, in this case you won't need to worry about proxies and certificates.
